# get jsp response as a string inside servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, java1.4

Is there a way to get response from a jsp file as a String inside servlet. Something like

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     String section1 = getResponseFromJSP();
     // do something else ...
     sendMailToUser(section1);
}
```

I'm using Servlet API 2.4 and java 1.4

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Please be clear with the understand that JSP is introduced to generate a request and the servlet acts as a controller in catering that request, and sending back the response, What exactly do you need from the JSP?

Comment: I have a JSP page which shows result of the calculation, the same result should be sent (by email) to the user

Comment: You submit that result as an action to a servlet, be it through ajax, and then do the needful in sending the mail

Comment: You can use `java.net.URL` and `java.net.URLConnection` class to request the web-resource.

Comment: @AVD cannot, jsp is not publicly accessible

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A better solution might be to use another template engine like freemarker or velocity, which are independent of the servlet api and more suited for text-based emails.

However, this is possible by wrapping the `HttpServletResponse` and overriding `getWriter` methods. The code below works for me on glassfish.

Servlet:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpServletResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
            private final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

            @Override
            public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
                return new PrintWriter(sw);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return sw.toString();
            }
        };
        request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp").include(request, responseWrapper);
        String content = responseWrapper.toString();
        System.out.println("Output : " + content);
        response.getWriter().write(content);
    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Hello world</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><%= "Hello world from a JSP!" %></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tested it, responseWrapper.toString(); returns empty String;

Comment: but this will do the job [link](http://blog.valotas.com/2011/09/get-output-of-jsp-or-servlet-response.html)
Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @lolotron: I modified the code and tested it on glassfish server. Not sure why the previous code using an OutputStream was not working.

Comment: What if the jsp page contains Some chinese (UTF-8) characters.
The responseWrapper will not get those chinese characters, instead it reads as junk, how can we get rid of it ?

Comment: @uday: You might want to ask this as a separate question and include the code so other can reproduce the issue. The chances of getting an answer are much higher that way.