# Need to get servlet output into html file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a html file which needs to take two servlet parameters the rest is hardcoded and then save itself to then send within a Javamail.

JSP getting parameters:

```
    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
            "/email.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

Your User Number is "<em><%=request.getParameter("USERNO")%></em>"
and your password is "<em><%= request.getParameter("PASSWORD")%></em>".
```

Just to confirm the servlet does give the parameters successfully when executed. The output of the jsp into the html file is given when I call a url like:

localhost/MailServlet/HTMLEmail?USERNO=1&PASSWORD=TEST

My idea was to save the bytes of the jsp output into a html file and then send that html file as an email. The thing is that when I try to copy from the url it becomes an infinite loop of where I cam calling the servlet.

Copying bytes code:

```
        System.out.println("opening connection");
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/MailServlet/HTMLEmail?USERNO="+USERNO+"&PASSWORD="+PASSWORD");
        System.out.println("urlString created with URL="+url);
        InputStream in = url.openStream();
        System.out.println("InputStream opened");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/****/workspace/HtmlMailServlet/WebContent/email.html"));
        System.out.println("FileOutputStream opened");
        System.out.println("reading file...");
        int length = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        // buffer for portion of data from connection
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        System.out.println("file read...");
        fos.close();
        in.close();
        System.out.println("file was downloaded");
```

Currently I am using a crazy 3 page string with two parameters passed inside which is obviously not good to look at but does the job. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher is what you are looking for:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721238/get-jsp-response-as-a-string-inside-servlet

Comment: Thanks been looking ages for a solution to this saved me a hell of a lot of code :)